# Can't Submit Axios Post form Nuxt.js (VueJS)

Tags: javascript, rest, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I'm playing around with my first ever form in Vue.  I've created my app with Nuxt.

I'm able to get data via an axios get request from my API but I can't seem to post data.

**new.vue**

```
<template>
    <section class="container">
    <div>
        <h1>Gins</h1>
        <form @submit.prevent="addGin">
        <h4>New Product</h4>
        <p>
            <label for="name" class="input-label">Title:</label>
            <input id="name" v-model="title" type="text" name="name" class="input">
        </p>
        <p>
            <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="button">Add Gin</button>
        </p>
        </form>
    </div>
    </section>
</template>
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      title: '',
      errors: []
    }
  },

  methods: {
    addGin() {
      axios.post('/apv/v1/gins', this.title)
        .then((Response) => {})
        .catch((err) => {
          this.errors.push(err)
        })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

When clicking the submit button, I'm not receiving any errors, but I can confirm no entry is added to my API database.

My API is running on a different server `localhost:4000` and I have set up the proxy in `nuxt.config.js`

```
 axios: {
    proxy: true
  },
  proxy: {
    '/api/v1/': 'http://localhost:4000'
  },
```

I've experimented with both `<form @submit.prevent="addGin">` and `<form v-on:submit.prevent="addGin">` but this doesn't seem to make a difference.

What else might I be missing?

Answer (score 1):

1. Add `@nuxtjs/axios` module into modules part of nuxt.config
2. Use `this.$axios` instead of imported one. Proof: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage

Comment: The link you posted doesn't show how Axios is being imported - the way the OP is using Axios seems rights to me, especially if they can `GET` data.    Seems like some sort of API error to me.   Plus, i would think there would be an undefined error in the console for axios.

Comment: axios is imported in modules part of nuxt config: https://i.imgur.com/tECRGR7.png
After it axios is available in components, stores, ...

Answer (score 0):

OK so was really close. Changing my axios params to `title: this.title`, apparently did the trick.